# app crashes when trying to modify value of an existing objective and save to core data, objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

What I am doing is

```
  Car *deletedCar = (Car*)[self.carArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Remove for data source
    [self.carArr removeObject:deletedCar];
    [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];

    NSError *error;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[CoreDataUtils shareCoreDataUtils] managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest=[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Car"];
    NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objectID==%@",deletedCar.objectID];
    fetchRequest.predicate=predicate;
    Car *car=[[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] lastObject];
    car.state = [NSNumber numberWithInt:DELETE_STATE];
    [CoreDataUtils saveContext:context];
```

but the app crashes right after `executeFetchRequest` and I have no clue why.
However if I do this, it works

```
    Car *deletedCar = (Car*)[self.carArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    deletedCar.state = [NSNumber numberWithInt:DELETE_STATE];

    // Remove for data source
    [self.carArr removeObject:deletedCar];
    [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];

    // Save to core data
    [CoreDataUtils saveContext:context];
```

Can anybody show what I have done wrong for the first way. All comments are welcomed here
Thanks

Comment: What does the crash log say? Did you try deleting the existing app and  running it again?

Comment: Why are you fetching a `Car` when you already have the one you want in `deletedCar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a fetchRequest NSManagedObjectContext has a method for exactly this

Try this instead `- (NSManagedObject *)objectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID`:

e.g

```
[context objectWithID:deletedCar.objectID]
```

Comment: A fetch request does not require a sort descriptor (unless you use it with a fetched results controller).